# Using advanced search operators in sending query to saerch engine using restful API

Tags: java, rest, elasticsearch, google-api, http-post

I am completely new to the use of rest API. However, these days, I need to employ the rest APIs provided in the [ChatNoir Search engine](https://www.chatnoir.eu/) to send some keywords and retrieve related documents. I already write the code to send a query and receive the results. When the query is simple like "hello world", it returns some results but when the number of query terms increases, it returns null. I think the search engine considers the query as an exact match. So, maybe I should use advanced search operators. In the [ChatNoir documents](https://www.chatnoir.eu/doc/api/), it is noted that we can use advanced search operators like other search engines. However, I don't know how to use that in JAVA. I used the "And" operator between query terms and send the query as a string, but it didn't work.
My source code is :

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("apikey", "$MyAPIKey");
    List<String> datasource=new ArrayList<>();
    datasource.add("cw09");
    json.put("index", datasource);
    json.put("pretty", true);
    json.put("query","hello world");*****

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://www.chatnoir.eu/api/v1/_search");
        StringEntity params = new StringEntity(json.toString());
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.setEntity(params);
        HttpResponse response= httpClient.execute(request);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
        JSONArray jsonArray=null;
        if (jsonObject!=null)
            jsonArray= jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
            for(int x = 0; x < jsonArray.length(); x++){
            String uuid=jsonArray.getJSONObject(x).getString("uuid");
            String score=String.valueOf(jsonArray.getJSONObject(x).getDouble("score"));
            System.out.print("uuid="+uuid+"\t"+"score="+score);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Therefore, the question is how to send query terms to search engine to not be considered as an exact match (Maybe using advanced search operators). For example, the query terms are term1, term2, term3, term4, term5, term6.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which elasticsearch query you are using? can you provide the search JSON ?

Comment: Thanks for considering. I don't know what you mean "elasticsearch"? The search engine is ChatNoir and I'm using the search API provided in this engine. Please check: https://www.chatnoir.eu/doc/api/

Comment: Then you shouldn't use the elasticsearch tag in your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search engine does not treat your query as an exact match phrase, but the default term operator is AND, meaning that all individual terms must appear in the document. Exact-match phrases are rewarded and appear before individual term matches, but are not required. So as your query gets longer, it is expected that you will get fewer results.

If you want to search for documents which contain only parts of a query, you have to formulate it as an OR query. For instance, `"hello world" OR "search engine"` would match documents containing either `hello world` or `search engine` or both. Do expect the results to be quite disconnected, though. Sometimes one term is much more common and matches many more documents, so you will have trouble finding results containing also the other term.

Answer (score 1):

In [ChatNoir documantation](https://www.chatnoir.eu/doc/api/) it is mentioned that you can use different Web operators to append multiple keywords.

> The simple module is the same module that our end-user web search
>   services uses. That means you can use all operators supported by the
>   web interface (AND , OR, -, "…", site:… etc.) also in your API query
>   string.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The problem is that I don't know how to use these web operators in sending query using rest API. Could you please guide me on what should I append to the above source code to be able to send multplei keyword? Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an API key to give it a try, but I can guess from the description that you can append the operators between different terms/keywords into the query string.